# SSRS SQL Dataset Properties

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services

Is it possible to have an "if" statement inside my SQL Query in the SSRS Dataset Properties?

For example, I want to run one query based on if a parameter value is true or not and another query for the opposite.

IF Parameters!StudentID.Count < 5
Select * from People
Else
Select * from Users
End if;

I don't know if it is possible to mix an SSRS expression inside a SQL script or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would **use parameters to accomplish this as well**, **join the two tables together** in your single data set and have the parameters drive the query result set. The overhead on your query will be minimal if you **cache the report** (which you always should). 
You could even drive it with case statements. **If the data sets are very different, then I suggest making two different reports**, as sometimes encapsulation at that level in SSRS can become hard to support longer term with multiple customers.

```
CASE 
     WHEN StudentIDint > 5 THEN People
     ELSE StudentID
  END
```

You cannot mix in SSRS expressions into the SQL Query interface, they are very different.

Here are the **best** **cheat sheets on SSRS Expressions** **[here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3011/sql-server-reporting-services-expressions-tips-and-tricks/), [here](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.com/2010/09/ssrs-expressions.html), and [here](http://pragmaticworks.com/Training/Resources/Cheat-Sheets/SSRS-Expression-Cheat-Sheet)**.

Learn more about [parameter use in SSRS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9bOO109bY8)

[image]

[image]